# How to convert Volume GUID of the mount point to actual path?

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, failovercluster

I'm using this code to get Path,VolumeLabel,TotalSize,FreeSpace:

```
gwmi -ComputerName $ComputerName -namespace root\MSCluster MSCluster_DiskPartition -Credential $cred -Authentication PacketPrivacy | Format-Table Path, VolumeLabel, TotalSize, FreeSpace -AutoSize
```

Output:

```
Path                                             VolumeLabel TotalSize FreeSpace
----                                             ----------- --------- ---------
U:                                               Archive1      4194184    379651
\\?\Volume{76795fb2-254e-454d-a95a-739018690cf4} Archive3      4194184    524883
X:                                               Archive2      4194184    735366
\\?\Volume{57e93910-60f9-44b9-8d9d-29d506e1e3d7} Archive4      4194184   1483274
```

**How I can get real path (or maybe drive name) of the mounting point from the Volume GUID ?**

[image]

I try to use .GetRelated class but with no success. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186277/how-to-get-drive-information-by-volume-id

Comment: @KostiaShiian I cannot use Win32_Volume or Win32_DiskDrive because I'm using MSCluster_DiskPartition class to get object from cluster perspective.

Comment: is this asking for a C# solution?  how would powershell play into this?

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa965286), the class has a `MountPoints` property that is, however, not supported before Windows Server 2012. @ALIENQuake: have you tried getting the `Win32_Volume` regardless and confirmed that it doesn't return information for `MSCluster_DiskPartition` volumes?

Answer (score 0):

I did test it with a vhd file which is mounted at `C:\test_vhd\`. It seems to work.

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_Volume -computername localhost | 
    ? { $PSItem.DeviceID.Contains("f91957ea-bb2f-11e4-9464-028037ec0200") } |
    Select-Object Name

    Name
    ----
    C:\test_vhd\
```

[image]